# Where do I read Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I've seen people saying that the Hunter x Hunter episode 148 corresponds with chapter 388, but on every site I've checked they only had up to chapter 360. With this in mind, Where do I go to read past this point, or did the anime actually surpass the manga?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend going to BN.com, Amazon.com, RightStuf.com and buying the manga.

Reading manga online while convenient and free for you supports neither the Mangaka or the Manga/Anime industry here in the USA, or your respective country

Comment: should point out that there are some places where you can legally read manga online but generally there is some catches like with [crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga) you need a subscription or the free-trial which counts as reading manga for free (in a limited sense)

Comment: This is true, but knowing which site is truly legal, and which sites are just saying they are legal.......And hey, a monthly membership to something still equates to spending quite less on an individual manga.  One can even go to libraries as some are starting to host manga sections.  I just tend to err on the side of caution when recommending where to find anime/manga, as this industry is niche enough that it needs all the financial support it can get.